# How to save as text a data frame with it's header?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have data frame loaded from a csv file and I processed the `dataframe.describe()` operation and I want to save the result as a text file.

Here is my code:

```
  data = spark.read.csv("iris.csv", header=True, sep=',')
  df = data.describe()
  df.rdd.map(lambda r: ",".join([str(c) for c in r])).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('describeResult')
```

The problem is that when process the `saveAsTextfile` opeartion the file received doesn't have the dataframe header. How can I fix it in order to save the whole dataframe including its header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv dataframe writer is able to write headers as well.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

`df.write.option("header", "true").csv(...)`

Note that if your dataframe is empty, headers won't be written.

Comment: I need to use `saveAsTextFile`because with `df.write` the result file name can not be predictable (sort of  part-00000-0db54427-ef17-43c0-8a0a-7b3c182d599e-c000) while using  `saveAsTextFile` the file is named part-00000

Comment: I don't understand the difference.. saveAsTextFile outputs one file per partition in a folder with the name you gave the same fashion a dataframe would do it.  You can coalesce if you only need one file

Comment: I meant that the name of the file when using `df.write` can not predicted (so I can not use it later) while when using `RDD.saveAsTextFile` the file result is staticly named part-00000 (When using coalesce in both cases)

Comment: In this case, why don't use the dataframe schema to create headers and then union this with your mapped RDD[String].  (scala) `sc.parallelize(List(df.columns.mkString(","))).union(...)`